# How to remove outliers from data set using Cook's distance?

Tags: r, statistics, outliers

We are required to remove outliers/influential points from the data set in a model. I have `400` observations and `5` explanatory variables.

I have tried this:

```
Outlier <- as.numeric(names (cooksdistance)[(cooksdistance > 4 / sample_size)))
```

Where Cook's distance is the calculated Cook's distance for the model.

The problem is that this doesn’t give me the actual outliers.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This community has a few [rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [norms](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and following them will help you get a good answer to your question. In particular, it’s best to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (a minimum, complete, and verifiable example).  Good advice for R-specific MVCEs is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) and [here](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/reprex-dos-and-donts.html).

Comment: I think you probably mean to remove outliers from your *data*, not from your *model*. This means you will need to reference your data frame in your code... It will be much easier to help if you follow some of Dan's advice and create a reproducible example.

Comment: 'R for Data Science' is an excellent resource. http://r4ds.had.co.nz/exploratory-data-analysis.html. Scroll down to 7.3.3 Unusual Values. Also, google removing outliers in r... there are many, many results.

Comment: Cook distance gives you the leverage points which are not necessarily outliers, also as other have mentioned you want to remove outliers before model fitting, if at all.

Answer (score 0):

In the formula you used for influential observation selection the condition should be as follows: if an observation has the Cook's distance more than 4 time of Cook's distance mean it can be considered ifluential (potentially an outlier).

> Cook's distance or Cook's D is a commonly used estimate of the influence of a data point
> when performing a least-squares regression analysis.
>
> In a practical ordinary least
> squares analysis, Cook's distance can be used in several ways: to indicate influential data > points that are particularly worth checking for validity; or to indicate regions of the
> design space where it would be good to be able to obtain more data points.
>
> In general use, those observations that have a
> cook’s distance greater than 4 times the mean may be classified as
> influential. This is not a hard boundary.

Please see as an example the [influential observation identification](http://r-statistics.co/Outlier-Treatment-With-R.html) for `ozone` data set:

```
ozone <- read.csv("http://rstatistics.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/ozone.csv")
m <- lm(ozone_reading ~ ., data=ozone)
cooksdistance <- cooks.distance(m)

influential <- as.numeric(names(cooksdistance)[(cooksdistance > 4 * mean(cooksdistance, na.rm = TRUE))]) 

ozone[influential, ]
#     Month Day_of_month Day_of_week ozone_reading pressure_height Wind_speed Humidity Temperature_Sandburg Temperature_ElMonte
# 19      1           19           1          4.07            5680          5       73                   52               56.48
# 23      1           23           5          4.90            5700          5       59                   69               51.08
# 58      2           27           5         22.89            5740          3       47                   53               58.82
# 133     5           12           3         33.04            5880          3       80                   80               73.04
# 135     5           14           5         31.15            5850          4       76                   78               71.24
# 149     5           28           5          4.82            5750          3       76                   65               51.08
# 243     8           30           1         37.98            5950          5       62                   92               82.40
# 273     9           29           3          4.60            5640          5       93                   63               54.32
# 286    10           12           2          7.00            5830          8       77                   71               67.10
#     Inversion_base_height Pressure_gradient Inversion_temperature Visibility
# 19                    393               -68                 69.80         10
# 23                   3044                18                 52.88        150
# 58                    885                -4                 67.10         80
# 133                   436                 0                 86.36         40
# 135                  1181                50                 79.88         17
# 149                  3644                86                 59.36         70
# 243                   557                 0                 90.68         70
# 273                  5000                30                 52.70         70
# 286                   337               -17                 81.14         20
```

Interpretation:

> Row 58, 133, 135 have very high ozone_reading.
>
> Rows 23, 135 and 149 have very high Inversion_base_height.
>
> Row 19 has very low Pressure_gradient.